# En un SQL report en local forma de ejecutar la SQL que tengo en el dataset en vez de tener que pasarle los datos

Tags: sql-server, reportviewer, ssrs

Estoy investigando las distintas posibilidades del `SQL Server Report`. He visto que en el servidor, cuando ejecutas un `report`, se conecta contra la cadena que le pongas de conexión en el `DataSource1` y luego ejecuta la sentencia `SQL` que hay en el `DataSet1`.

Al comprobar con el `ReporViewer` para un report en local, veo que o le añado un `datasource` nuevo o no me ejecuta el `DataSet` que ya tiene él. Y además da el siguiente error:

> No se ha proporcionado ninguna instancia de origen de datos para el origen de datos 'DataSet1'.

Hay forma de ejecutar un `report` en local sin tener que pasarle los datos?

La intención es que los `reports` lo hagan los consultores y a los programadores no les molesten con estas cosas.

Gracias.

Comment: Si bien no entiendo correctamente la pregunta completa, `Hay forma de ejecutar un report en local si tener que pasarle los datos` <--- no, no se puede ejecutar un reporte (local o no) sin pasarle datos.

Comment: Lo digo porque cuando está en el servidor SSRS para obtener los datos lo hace mediante la cadena de conexión que hay en el DataSource y con la query del DataSet. Y si ese mismo report lo ejecutas en local, ya te tienes que pasar los datos.

Comment: Cuando tienes el "reporte local", tienes la estructura y diseño, nunca con los datos incluidos

Comment: He visto en esta página [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607382/Running-an-RDLC-SQL-Report-in-ASP-NET-without-SSRS] que hacen una proposición interesante. Ya que el report es un XML editarlo para sacar la query y ejecutarla desde la aplicación. A mi por lo menos me lo ha parecido. Aunque sigo sin entender por que microsoft no deja ejecutar la query de un report en local, cosa que crystal report si que hace...